# Derivative of a function from a closed Riemannian manifold to a Hilbert space

Tags: derivatives, hilbert-spaces, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, frechet-derivative

Let $F$ be a [Hilbert space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space) and $\Theta$ a $d$-dimensional [closed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_manifold) [Riemannian manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemannian_manifold).
Consider the twice [Fréchet differentiable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative) functions $R \colon F \to [0, \infty)$ and $\phi \colon \Theta \to F$ and for $m \in \mathbb{N}_{> 0}$ the discrete objective function
$$
F_m \colon (\Omega^*)^m \to \mathbb R, \qquad
\big((r_k, \theta_k)\big)_{k = 1}^{m} 
\mapsto R\left(\frac{1}{m}\sum_{k = 1}^{m} h(r_k) \phi(\theta_k)\right) + \frac{\lambda}{m} \sum_{k = 1}^{m} h(r_k),
$$
where $\Omega^* := (0, \infty) \times \Theta$.

On page 5 of [Chizat - Sparse Optimization on Measures with Over-parametrized Gradient Descent](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10107-021-01636-z) (available on [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.10300)), it is claimed that as "gradients are characterised by the relation $\text{d} F_m(x)(\delta x) = \langle \nabla F_m(x), \delta x \rangle$, we get" a certain expression for $\nabla_{r_i} F_m$ and $\nabla_{\theta_i} F_m$, where $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is a certain metric on $(\Omega^*)^m$. This claim is backed up by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient#Riemannian_manifolds) if I am not mistaken.

I want to verify those expressions so I tried to compute $\text{d}F_m(x)(\delta x)$, where, presumably, $x \big((r_k, \theta_k)\big)_{k = 1}^{m} \in (\Omega^*)^m$ and $\partial x \in T_x (\Omega^*)^m$. (As $(\Omega^*)^m$ and $\mathbb R$ are Riemannian manifolds, I understand this derivative as the derivative of a function between differentiable manifolds).
To this end, I write $F_m = R \circ \Phi_m + \lambda H_m$, where $\Phi_m(x) := \frac{1}{m}\sum_{k = 1}^{m} h(r_k) \phi(\theta_k)$ and $H_m(x) := \frac{1}{m} \sum_{k = 1}^{m} h(r_k)$.
Because of the sum structure, the derivative of $\Phi_m$ is the uniformly weighted sum of the derivatives of $h(r_k) \phi(\theta_k)$, for $k \in \{ 1, \ldots, m \}$, which I want to compute using the [product rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule).

> BUT: What kind of derivative is
> $$
> \text{d} \phi(x)(\delta x)
> $$
> supposed to be?
> It can't be a Fréchet derivative $\text{D} f(x)[h] \in Y$, where $f \colon X \to Y$ and $x, h \in X$ and $X, Y$ are [normed spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normed_vector_space) (because $(\Omega^*)^m$ is not a normed space) because $x \in (\Omega^*)^m$ and $\partial x \in T_x (\Omega^*)^m$ (where $T_x M$ denotes the [tangent space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_space) of $M$ at $x$) and it cannot be the [derivative of a map between manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_manifold#Differentiability_of_mappings_between_manifolds), as $F$ might be infinite-dimensional and hence not a manifold in the standard sense. (I am aware of, but don't know anything about [Hilbert manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_manifold).)

Comment: Read that paper a while back, might be wrong but I think the gradient there is a vector not a covector and $\langle \nabla F, \delta x \rangle$ is inner product not duality, done by identifying the (covector) gradient with the (vector) gradient through the metric. So you can always pick a chart, go to $\mathbb{R}^d$ equipped with inner product $g_{ij}v^iw^j$. Now the map is between two inner product spaces and you can take the Fréchet derivative. I guess you should be able to reinterpret the results in coordinat-free form by writing $g_{ij}v^iw^j$ as $\langle v, w \rangle_\theta$ again.

Comment: @RozaTh Thank you for your reply. What are the $g_{i, j}$ in your answer? So do you think that the following would be a sensible definition for the "Fréchet" differentiability of a function $\phi \colon \Theta \to F$: $$\text{"if for every open set $U \subset \Theta$ (for which there exists a diffeomorphism $\psi \colon U \to \phi(U) \overset{\text{open}}{\subset} \mathbb{R}^d$)} \\ \text{the map $\psi^{-1} \circ \phi \colon \phi(U) \to F$ is Fréchet differentiable"?}$$

Comment: $g_{ij}$s are components of the Riemannian metric in chart coordinate basis, i.e. $g(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i},\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j})$.

Comment: As for your definition I think it should be $\psi:U\to\phi(U)$ and $\phi\circ\psi^{-1}$. It could work but the inner product on $\mathbb{R}^d$ is not the standard one but as I said $g_{ij}v^iv^j$. The main question is whether this definition is coordinate-free or not. It might be an overkill but you can always use Nash embedding theorem; isometrically embed $\Theta$ in $\mathbb{R}^d$, take the Fréchet derivative but restrict the input point to the manifold and the input direction to the manifolds tangent space at that point.

Comment: @RozaTh Thank you for your input. If you would formulate what you have written into an answer, I will gladly accept it.